# Http Request For Protocol Process

Tags: php, html

I have a script that takes 36 students in a class and then loops through all of them and goes to the grade table and takes the average of each student.
My question is, when registering this request, does it count as just one or more than 36? That is, does each query that we run to the database also count as a request? Thank you!

Comment: Who are you registering the request with? Perhaps [a bit of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could illustrate your question. It would also be nice to know why you want to know this? What if the answer is 1, or what if it is 36?

Answer (score 0):

Depends of how it's implemented.(in terms of http-request)

Let's say all the work it's on php and it's needed one http call to get the result. Obvious is just 1 http-request. It's irelevant how many sql queries are involved, code design(classes involved,etc). We count only http access via browser.

But, let's say you get the list from java-script and for each student you do a ajax call via php then it will need [no. of students] of http-requests.

Hint: check developer tools from browser and count http-requests.